# Azure blob storage networking rules (Ip) for Azure data warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-storage, data-warehouse

I need to load external data (in blob storage) to my Azure data warehouse using Polybase.  I had it working fine when I was using Classic Azure Storage.

Recently, I have to update our Storage to ARM and I could not figure out how to set up the firewall rule on the ARM Storage to my Azure data warehouse.  If I set the firewall to "All networks" everything works seamlessly.  However, I cannot let the blob wide open.

I tried using nslookup to find the outbound ip for our Azure Data warehouse and put the value into the Firewall of the Storage; I got "This request is not authorized to perform this operation." error

Is there a way I can find the ip address for an Azure Data warehouse?  Or I should use different approach to make it work?

Any Suggestions are appreciated.

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Under the section 1.1 Create a Credential, it states:

> **Don't skip this step** if you are using this tutorial as a template for loading your own data. To access data through a credential, use the following script to create a database-scoped credential, and then use it when defining the location of the data source.

```
  -- A: Create a master key.
-- Only necessary if one does not already exist.
-- Required to encrypt the credential secret in the next step.

CREATE MASTER KEY;


-- B: Create a database scoped credential
-- IDENTITY: Provide any string, it is not used for authentication to Azure storage.
-- SECRET: Provide your Azure storage account key.


CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL AzureStorageCredential
WITH
    IDENTITY = 'user',
    SECRET = '<azure_storage_account_key>'
;


-- C: Create an external data source
-- TYPE: HADOOP - PolyBase uses Hadoop APIs to access data in Azure blob storage.
-- LOCATION: Provide Azure storage account name and blob container name.
-- CREDENTIAL: Provide the credential created in the previous step.

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureStorage
WITH (
    TYPE = HADOOP,
    LOCATION = 'wasbs://<blob_container_name>@<azure_storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net',
    CREDENTIAL = AzureStorageCredential
);
```

**Edit**: (additional way to access Blobs from ADW through the use of SAS):

> You also can create a Storage linked service by using a shared access signature. It provides the data factory with restricted/time-bound access to all/specific resources (blob/container) in the storage.

A shared access signature provides delegated access to resources in your storage account. You can use a shared access signature to grant a client limited permissions to objects in your storage account for a specified time. You don't have to share your account access keys. The shared access signature is a URI that encompasses in its query parameters all the information necessary for authenticated access to a storage resource. To access storage resources with the shared access signature, the client only needs to pass in the shared access signature to the appropriate constructor or method. For more information about shared access signatures, see Shared access signatures: Understand the shared access signature model.
Full document can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage)

Comment: Adam, thanks for spending time on my question.  Just to clarify, I am not having issue on connecting to the ADW (Azure Data Warehouse).  My issue is I am not able to use External Table in ADW to read (blob) files that are storing in Azure Blob Storage, after I move my Azure Storage account from Classic to ARM.  I could have done that if I wild open the Azure Storage to the public but this is not going to work in my environment.  I would like to limit the access (Firewall setting in Azure Storage) of the Azure Storage either just to the ADW if possible.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the clarification, you should use a different approach if your blob is not set to public, specifically the script mentioned in this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-load-from-azure-blob-storage-with-polybase 
, under the 1.1 section: 
Don't skip this step if you are using this tutorial as a template for loading your own data. To access data through a credential, use the following script...
If this works, let me know and i could edit my answer.

Comment: Adam, I already have these objects created in ADW and it works perfectly on *classic* Azure Storage.  It works on *ARM* Storage only if I have set it to public.  I wanted to limit the access to of the Storage to just the ADW or the services without the subscription (at least) but I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: I added an edit to the answer with the bellow info. Note that you should still access blobs via the initial provided response without making the blob as public. I'd recommend checking SAS bellow, and if you have an NSG to verify if access is not restricted or disabled for some resources:
You also can create a Storage linked service by using a shared access signature. It provides the data factory with restricted/time-bound access to all/specific resources (blob/container) in the storage.

Comment: I have tried SAS too.  It works *only* if I select "All networks" on the [Firewalls and virtual networks] on the Storage.  If I want to limit the access and choose "Selected networks", I have to provide Address Range to specify the source of the connection request (i.e. ADW).  This is what I am not sure what to put, or there is another better setup that I don't know.